# How to display value in real time without refresh page with React and SocketIO?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I develop a basic application with NodeJS, React and SocketIO.

My NodeJS server sends socket to the React clients with a table of players (string value). I  want display this table of players in the react view, and refresh it dynamically when it changes.

I tried some solutions but nothing works great. Have you ideas to do that or to improve my code ?

Thanks

Constructor : this.players[]

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    }

    this.gameId = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.players = [];

}
```

showPlayer : display list of players with cards

```
    showPlayers = () => {
     const  classes  = this.props;
    let playersCards = [];
    console.log(this.players);

this.players.foreach(function(p){

      playersCards.push(
        <Card className={classes.card}>
           <CardHeader
             avatar={
               <Avatar style={{backgroundColor: "#00FF00"}} aria-label="Recipe">
                 R
               </Avatar>
             }
             action={
               <IconButton>
                 <MoreVertIcon />
               </IconButton>
             }
             title={p}
             subheader=""
           />
       </Card>
      )
    }

    return playersCards;
}
```

Socket.io : get the table of players updated

```
  socket.on('ack-join-game', function(res){
      this.players =  res.dataGame.players;
  });
```

Render :

```
   const  classes  = this.props;
    return(
      <div className="GameConfig">
        <h1>Salon de jeu</h1>
        <div className="well" style={this.wellStyles}>
                  <h2>Informations</h2>
                  Id : {this.gameId}
                  <br></br>
                  <h2>Players (0/2)</h2>
                  <div id="cards">
                  </div>
                  {this.showPlayers()}
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <br></br>
              <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" bsSize="large" block>
              Lancer la partie
            </Button>

          </form>
        </div>
        <ToastContainer store={ToastStore}/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your players in the state of your component as changing them affects what is going to be rendered. Also, you can remove the endpoint if it is never going to change at runtime :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        players = [],
    }

    this.gameId = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
}
```

Then call `setState` to update players and refresh the component in your socket event :

```
socket.on('ack-join-game', res => {
    this.setState({ players: res.dataGame.players })
});
```

Now, your players will need to be accessed via `this.state.players` instead of `this.players`.

You could also completely remove your `showPlayers` function using `map`:

```
const { players } = this.state
const { card } = this.props.classes

return (
    <div className="GameConfig">
        <h1>Salon de jeu</h1>
        <div className="well" style={this.wellStyles}>
            <h2>Informations</h2>
            Id : {this.gameId}
            <br></br>
            <h2>Players (0/2)</h2>
            <div id="cards">
            </div>
            {players.map(player =>
                <Card className={card} key={player}>
                    <CardHeader
                        avatar={
                            <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: "#00FF00" }} aria-label="Recipe">
                                R
                            </Avatar>
                        }
                        action={
                            <IconButton>
                                <MoreVertIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                        }
                        title={player}
                        subheader=""
                    />
                </Card>
            )}
            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <br></br>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" bsSize="large" block>
                    Lancer la partie
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ToastContainer store={ToastStore} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with 

    socket.on('ack-join-game', function(res){ *** }